# Autolayout constraints and iPhone 6/6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, iphone-6-plus

I'm new to iOS development, and am having trouble with AutoLayout constraints. I'm trying to "pin" a label to the right side of a TableViewCell. It works fine in the iPhone 4s-5s simulators, but not in the iPhone 6 (plus) simulators.

The constraints on the label are top space to container margin, and leading space to container margin like this:

[image]

In the 4s/5/5s simulator it looks like I would expect it to, but the 6 plus simulator, I get this:

[image]

The same problem exists with the 6, but to a lesser degree.

If I swap out leading space to margin for trailing space to margin, the label falls off, leaving a blank cell in every simulator.

However, if I add the exact same layout constraints to a normal view, the label aligns fine. This is only occurring in the custom TableViewCell.

Both width and height are set to any in the size class. If I expand the width of the cell, move the label to the right, and then shrink the cell back so the label is off the side and then have the constraints adjusted, the label will at least get closer to the right on the 6+. The problem with this is that on anything smaller, it falls off the side.

How can I get the label to align to the right in all devices in the TableViewCell, or is this just a problem in the simulators?  I don't exactly have a 6+ to test it on.

Comment: If you're trying to pin it to the *right* side, why are you constraining it to the *left*?

Comment: If I pin it to the left like [this](http://gyazo.com/d6af264fd3d137572c18a802bb765495), it falls of the screen and I get [this](http://gyazo.com/60a2183e661f7a5659253e131b383524)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, to pin an object to the right hand side of a view, the only constraints you need are

- top space to container
- trailing space to container
- fixed width
- fixed height

If the width of your label is variable, you probably want to:

- right align the label
- remove the fixed width constraint and add either a lead space to container <= constraint or pin it to a sibling view that can change width.

If after changing the leading space to a trailing space constraint in your example you are seeing the labels disappear, I would make sure that your parent table view constraints are correct and that the tableview isnt bleeding out over the edge of the screen.

Comment: thanks, but for example I have a view width is self.contentView.frame.size.width-20
for 6 plus I can do it like:
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[_bgView(400)]-10-|"
but it will bigger than iPhone 5 & 6's frame width, how to get the dynamic value to take place of the '400' in the constraint bgView(400).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> If I swap out leading space to margin for trailing space to margin, the label falls off, leaving a blank cell in every simulator

Not so. Remove the leading space constraint. Make a trailing space constraint from the right edge of the label to the right edge of the `contentView` - not to its margin, but the view itself. That's all you need.

Comment: I did [that](http://gyazo.com/d6af264fd3d137572c18a802bb765495) before, and I get [this](http://gyazo.com/60a2183e661f7a5659253e131b383524) as a result.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. Do you need me to fix it for you? Post it on github and I will.

Comment: By the way, I would suggest that fluoresce is probably right; it sounds / looks like the problem here is merely that whole table is disappearing off to the right. If you do what I described, the label _will_ appear at the right side of the table, so if you're not seeing it, it must be because you are not seeing the right side of the table. Make sure the table view _itself_ is pinned on all four sides to its superview.

Comment: @flouresce That was the problem. I had some confusion because the parent view was a tableViewController I added in the storyboard, and there was nothing about constraining the tableView itself in my learning material. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Not to its margin, but the view itself." This was essential for me... it usually automatically assigns the constraint to the margin instead of the view...